# F# add new source file

Tags: visual-studio, f#

In an F# project in Visual Studio 2013, how do you create a new F# source file and add it to the project? There exists the File/New/File menu option, but while that can create a new source file, it doesn't seem to add it to the project.

Comment: Right click on the project and then add -> new item like you do with every other kind of projects in VS.

Comment: @MatteoMosca - that is the answer :)

Comment: @MatteoMosca - true, you do have to add them in the correct order though :)

Comment: Yeah, exactly my point, since F# reads files in the order they are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project and then add -> new item like you do with every other kind of project in VS.